# If $p$ is an odd prime number, prove that $1^23^25^2\dotsb(p-4)^2(p-2)^2 \equiv (-1)^{(p+1)/2} \pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> If $p$ is an odd prime number, prove that $1^{2}3^{2}5^{2}\dotsb(p-4)^2(p-2)^2 \equiv  (-1)^{(p+1)/2} \pmod p$

I thought maybe I could use $p-k \equiv -k \pmod p$ to try and reduce the LHS, but I'm not sure how to account for the negative sign. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Rewrite $a^2$ as $a\cdot (p-a)\cdot(-1)$ and use Wilson

Answer (score 1):

We have that, modulo an odd prime $p$,
$$\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2}(p-2k)^2\equiv 4^{(p-1)/2}\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2}k^2\equiv  2^{p-1}\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2}k\cdot \prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2} (k-p)\\\equiv (-1)^{(p-1)/2}\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2}k\cdot \prod_{j=(p+1)/2}^{p-1}j\equiv (-1)^{(p-1)/2}\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}k\equiv (-1)^{(p-1)/2}$$
where we used $2^{p-1}\equiv 1$ ([Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)) and $\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}k\equiv 1$ ([Wilson's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem)).